# Physical keyboard doesn't disable when using a virtual keyboard

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML application that is supposed to have a login feature, and i'm to use a virtual keyboard instead of a physical one. The keyboard works, but i would love to disable the physical one and have the user use the virtual one. I used the following code:

```
$('#Document').keypress(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

But when i do that, it disables input for the entire application, so i tried to be specific like:

```
$('#loginUsername').keypress(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But the keyboard doesn't work.
I'm using the keyboard found here:[Virtual Keyboard](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard)

How can i go about this?

Comment: Ugh, please don't do that.

Comment: Have you tried the 3rd example on the URL you posted?

Comment: Disabling the physical keyboard is a really lame way of trying to promote security. if it's being submitted by a form and a user has spyware, their input *will* be captured, keyboard or not. All you're doing to do is infuriate people by presenting a keyboard that's difficult to use, and probably will not even match their keyboard layout.

Comment: Believe me i'd rather not do the virtual keyboard, but when you get requirements you follow them to the lette. Especially when you get paid to do so...

Comment: There's a spectrum between being stubborn about not doing it and [rigid compliance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malicious_compliance).  With any luck you'll be able to remove this abomination when the client comes to their senses. You're basically throwing anyone with a screen reader to the wolves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked:

```
$('#UserName').keypress(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    lockInput: true,
    preventPaste: true
});
```

Just Specified the 'lockInput' keyword to true, also the 'preventPaste' to stop coping and pasting.

Hope Someone will find it uselfull

Answer (score 2):

First, I feel duty-bound to say: virtual keyboards are almost always *terrible*, and with the exception of touchscreen-only kiosks, there are virtually no reasons to use them. So, please think of your users.

But, that said: to disable key presses in an input, return `false` from the keypress handler:

```
$("input").on("keypress", function() {
    return false;
});
```